# Why does root need to enter a password when executing specific commands?

Tags: rhel, password, root

On a certain RHEL5 machine, when root is executing commands such as `passwd someuser` or any other privileged command, the root password is requested for verification and the command can't be executed without it.

Example:

```
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)  
groups=0(root),10(wheel)
# passwd someuser
Password:(need to enter root verification password to proceed)
New user password:
Retype new password:
```

- root user is present in the `/etc/sudoers` file as shown below:

  ```
  root ALL=(ALL) ALL
  ```
- All basic files in `/etc/pam.d/` such as `login`,
  `passwd`, `password-auth`, `password-auth-ac`, `system-auth-ac`, `system-auth`, `sudo`, `sudo-l` are the same as those on another machine that doesn't behave in the same way.
- SElinux is disabled.
- `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is unchanged and consistent with other machines.

  ```
  passwd:         files ldap 
  group:          files ldap 
  shadow:         files ldap 
  hosts:          files dns
  networks:       files
  protocols:      files
  services:       files
  ethers:         files
  rpc:            files
  netgroup:       files
  sudoers:  files ldap
  ```
- Not much information can be seen from logs files as listed below when executing passwd command:

  `/etc/log/secure` - empty (Unfortunately I'm not allowed to touch rsyslog)

  `/etc/log/auth.log`

  ```
  sshd[xxxxx]:  Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for root from 127.0.0.XX port XXXXX ssh2
  sshd[xxxxx]:  pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
  ```
- The same thing happens when connected directly (without ssh) to the console.

Has anyone experienced similar behavior?

Or can you please recommend any debugging flag or a method that can help in finding the cause of the problem?

Comment: What is the password prompt for "any other privileged command"?

Comment: Other privileged commands that I have noticed so far are not default linux commands. Usually these commands can be executed only by super user root but without authentication. Commands such as "cat /etc/passwd, "crontab -l -u someuser", "su - someuser", do not request root authentication when logged in with root.

Comment: Well, if some commands sometimes require password then you probably won't get answers here.

Comment: Usually neither "some" nor the default linux commands require password. passwd command shouldn't be asking for root password when run by root.

Comment: That is rather odd. As @3nk1 says, passwd never asked me for root password when changing the password of another user as root/in sudo.

Comment: Can you run `sudo rpm -V passwd shadow-utils` and see if there are any errors?  You could be running a locally modified version of passed.

Comment: Is `passwd` aliased to some other command?

Comment: Hi guys, thank you all for your replies and suggestions. @MarkPlotnick output of rpm verify shows inconsistency of following files with rpm database: /etc/pam.d/passwd; /etc/default/useradd; /etc/login.defs; /usr/bin/chage; /usr/bin/gpasswd. However it is same for other machine which have similar configuration but not the same behavior. Anyway tomorrow I will try to dig deeper in that direction

Comment: @AndrewHelen, no passwd is not aliased to other command.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely related to your pam configuration.  I'm not sure if it's exactly the same in RHEL 5, but in RHEL 6, authentication by account succeeds by default for users with a UID < 500 because `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` contains the line:

```
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
```

Like other authenication related tools on RHEL, `/usr/bin/passwd` makes use of pam and the configuration in `/etc/pam.d`.

Restoring `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` by running `yum reinstall pam` or extracting `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` from the rpm is probably your safest bet.  The existing `system-auth` file may not be overwritten, but written as `system-auth.rpmnew`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thank you all for your help.

The problem was solved after generating new ssh keys:

```
# ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I found discrepancy between authorized_keys2 and id_rsa.pub files and thus generated new keys. I honestly had no idea that it could solve the problem as I stopped suspecting ssh since I've noticed that problem was happening on console connection too.